# Want to check Apple push notification Service on my device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, notifications

I have created iphone application which support Apple push notification service.
 I also configured the server on windows which sends my device id to apple server.
 I gets device ID whenever I launch application. But still i wont get any notification from
 apple server, where notifications were also send to apple server from my local windows 
server.

How should I check where my APN application is going wrong? Bcoz on server side, server didnt get any error message during sending messages to APN server, also on my iphone application I have properly registered for remote notifications. But still I dont get any notifications. Please help

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not working for you, iron out you problems before letting third parties test your application. If your having trouble receiving notifications it won't be any better for the testers.

As how to actually beta test your app. Go to a commercial outfit or ad hoc by:

1. Have all testers submit their devices UDID as listed on the "Summary" tab from the device page in the iTunes application (click "serial number" to display the UDID).
2. Enter all UDID's into the device list on your iTunes Connect account.
3. Create a new provisioning profile with all your testers devices enabled.
4. Export your new app provisioning profile to xCode and rebuild.
5. Send the provisioning profile and fresh app to your testers instruction them to drop both on iTunes to install it on their iPhone.
6. Really, really thank your testers for their hard work.

Comment: Thank you Niels Castle. Actually I am missing in creating certificate.